# Caesar cipher - What's wrong?

Tags: c++, string, encryption

I'm having the problem with launching encrypting program. For single words strings it works well (for example, abcd), but when i type two or three or more words (a sentence, for example, abcd ab ac) it doesn't ask for a key, but rewrites the sentence I typed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int key, l;
        char choose;
        string message;
        cout<<"Type the message"<<endl;
        cin>>message;
        cout<<"Give me a key from 0 to 26"<<endl;
        cin>>key;
        for (int i=0,l=message.size(); i<=l; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(message[i]))
            {
                if (isupper(message[i]))
                {
                    cout<<(char)('A'+(message[i]-'A'+key)%26);
                }
                if (islower(message[i]))
                {
                    cout<<(char)('a'+(message[i]-'a'+key)%26);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<message[i];
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if we could see what code you wrote. Otherwise it is a contest of who can guess and/or read your mind.

Comment: Sorry, I forgott about it. I edited it.

Comment: If I run it and input several words, it does not repeat the sentence I typed; it asks for a key, then prints the first word I input. Are you sure you're running this program?

Comment: I also ran this program and it worked. Can you post your output also?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
std::getline(std::cin, message);
```

---

*cin* does only read until the next whitespace, the rest of the input is being kept in the stream buffer so that you get the next word of your sentence entered in the first step as input for your second *cin*.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you explain to me why my solution wasn't correct?